# Analyze memory and cpu peaks of docker container

Tags: docker, performance-monitoring, memory-usage, ubuntu-16.04

I want to analyze the maximum memory (RAM + swap) usage and the maximum cpu utilization of a single docker container.

I know that one can use `docker stats` and */sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker//memory.stat* (and the corresponding cpu pseudo-file) to get live information, but fetching this information every few ms does not seem a good way to go to look for peaks.

Is there any way to achieve this? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and 1.11.2 on my host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give [Cadvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) a try. The interface is pretty basic, but it has everything you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There is more monitoring tools for Docker, not only cAdvisor - http://veggiemonk.github.io/awesome-docker/#monitoring

But all of them read metric value for period, which is usually >1sec. If you need to monitor peaks with ms resolution, then you need to code your own solution.

TBH: 1 sec metric resolution is enough for 99% (non realtime) applications.